# problem with importing json in a react typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

```
import { select } from "d3-selection";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { feature, topology } from "topojson";
import us from "./us.json";

const Map: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
const mapRef = React.createRef<SVGSVGElement>();

useEffect(() => {
    createMap();
});

const createMap = () => {
    const map = select(mapRef.current);
    map.selectAll("path").data(feature(us, us.objects.states));
};

return <svg ref={mapRef} />;
};
export default Map;
```

i'm having a typescript error on the line `feature(us, us.objects.states)`, where us gives me the type error string is not assignable to type Topology. and after looking at the json file the type is actually `"type":"Topology"`, but i can see how typescript would see it as a string instead. How do i fix this issue?

Comment: Having this same problem, have you found anything?